# display frequency of a date range in a bar chart

Tags: r, date, range, bar-chart

I have a very big data frame consisting of data like this:

```
  PENR     ANFDAT     ENDDAT
1 1110 1990-02-01 1998-10-29
2 1981 1998-02-19 1998-02-20
3 6317 1994-11-01 1999-06-30
4 2039 1998-12-01 1999-04-30
```

(get it from here)

```
df <- structure(list(PENR = c(1110L, 1981L, 6317L, 2039L), ANFDAT = structure(c(7336, 10276, 9070, 10561), class = "Date"), ENDDAT = structure(c(10528, 10277, 10772, 10711), class = "Date")), .Names = c("PENR", "ANFDAT", "ENDDAT"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

ANFDAT stands for the beginning of a certain status, ENDDAT stends for the termination of this status

I want to display this data as a bar chart. Each bar should stand for a date. the height of each bar should represent the number of records (PENR) having the status on this date.

As the data frame is very big I look for an efficient way to achieve this.

**[EDIT]**

Seems like my question is misleading. Here's what I try to do:

1. Generate a data frame for each date from `min(df$ANFDAT)` to `max(df$ENDDAT)`. This can be done easily with

   ```
   df1 <- data.frame(DATE = seq(min(df$ANFDAT), max(df$ENDDAT), by = "day"))
   ```
2. For each row in `df1$DATE`, count the number of records in `df` that have `ANFDAT >= DATE` and `ENDDAT <= DATE`. Store the results in `df1$RECORDS`
3. Generate a barplot out of `df1`. This probably can be done like that (untested)

   ```
   df2 <- df1$RECORDS
   row.names(df2) <- df1$DATE
   barplot(df2$RECORDS)
   ```

My problem is to find an efficient way to do #2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sapply` over the unique dates to count the number of records.

The whole procedure:

```
DATE <- seq.int(min(df$ANFDAT), max(df$ENDDAT), by = "day")

df1 <- data.frame(RECORDS = sapply(DATE, function(x)
                                sum(df[["ANFDAT"]] <= x &  df[["ENDDAT"]] >= x)))

rownames(df1) <- DATE
barplot(df1$RECORDS)
```

Comment: thank you! seems like my question indeed is a bit misleading. I'll try to improve it!